# I give up. Getting runtime erro 438 and wondering where my code is flawed

Tags: excel, vba

Making a sort of budget calculator

I've listed some bills of mine and their respective prices

If a row for a bill contains 'paid' in one of its columns, the value (from another column on the same row) should be added to a total value of all bills paid.

That value should then be subtracted from a value of another cell representing the sum of all bills I have, paid or not.

I've tried representing the values as variables to avoid the .Activate and .Value methods. I figured I'd just write everything out as plain as possible and it still didn't work.

```
Sub AddPaidAllo3()

    Workbooks("budget-beta.xlsx").Activate
    Dim PaidBills As Currency

    For i = 21 To 34

'reference column with "paid" string

        Sheet2.Cells(i, 4).Activate
            If ActiveCell.Value = "paid" _
                Then PaidBills = PaidBills + Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value

'above Cells(i,2) contains the cost    

    Next i

'A2 contains a total of all bills ---- A5 *should* contain the value of remaining bills to be paid

    Sheet2.Range("A5") = Sheet2.Range("A2").Value - PaidBills

End Sub
```

I expect my cell value to change but i get runtime error 1004 for an object or program defined error. Where did I go wrong? It doesn't highlight any particular object.

Comment: Dont' you want `Sheet2.Range("a5") = Sheet2.Range("A2").Value -PaidBills`?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/writing-assignment-statements

Comment: So i fixed that and now i get error 1004, program or object defined error

Comment: that was a helpful link, im gonna noodle with the code now